# JSP is not found with error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after renaming it

Tags: jsp, servlets, tomcat9

I am facing typical issue with the simple servlet, JSP application. I have developed some JSP pages and servlet. It works fine. After it, I have changed JSP file names to case sensitive like`AddEmployee.jsp` to `addEmployee.jsp` and `Home.jsp` to `home.jsp`. I have also changed request dispatcher URL with new names. But then I facing exception

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/jsp/employee/addEmployee_jsp

while loading JSP.

I am using Eclipse IDE and tomcat 9.0 application server.

Comment: please post your request dispatcher code

Comment: I am dispatching request with code - request.getRequestDispatcher("/employee/addEmployee.jsp").forward(request, response);

Comment: why /employee then .jsp ?

Comment: jsp is in "employee" folder in webcontent. So

Comment: your employee folder should be directly under your WEB-INF folder.

Comment: try  removing /employee

Comment: It won't work. I have changed my tomcat and it works fine. But still not able to know why it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Check spellings first. Like,
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jsp/employee/**addEmployee_jsp** instead of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jsp/employee/**addEmployee.jsp**. The clean and build the project. Finally run. Maybe it would work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem after cleaning Tomcat work directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to solve the problem.

1. go to server tabs
2. expand the server
3. right click on your project
4. select clean Module Work directory

[image]